# Native Integration in Silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight-4.0, pinvoke

a question concerning the new concept of Trusted Applications in Silverlight 4:

I gather that trusted applications run outside the browser with elevated trust. Will it therefore be possible to call arbitrary functions in unmanaged DLLs (by means of DllImport) from a trusted application or is this feature still reserved to proper desktop applications?

Thank you very much in advance and kind regards,

Marc Frei

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Silverlight 4 does not allow calling unmanaged code via P/Invoke. You can only call native code using the COM via the [AutomationFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.automation.automationfactory%28VS.95%29.aspx) class. However, calling native code was added to [Silverlight 5](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlight_sdk/archive/2011/09/27/pinvoke-in-silverlight5-and-net-framework.aspx).